# How long it takes for a smart contract to be mapped by Polygon Token Mapper?

Tags: nft, polygon, bridge

So, I've created my smart contracts (ERC-1155 with transparent upgradable proxy) both for ethereum and polygon, deployed and verified. Then I use the [mapper tool](https://mapper.polygon.technology/) of Polygon for mapping(?). I've been waiting for a couple of hours now and they mapped yet. I've read this [medium page](https://medium.com/@polygoncommunitychannel/polygon-bridge-for-matic-eth-nft-f75c6e0d6020) and here it says

> And it got mapped after 3 days with this Ethereum and Polygon.

Do I really have to wait 2-3 days just to test smart contracts? Does anyone know anything about the waiting time for this?

Comment: It took about 20 hours (test networks) and I didn't receive an e-mail about the confirmation as said on the mapper tool's web page. I checked from the same website and saw my contracts were mapped.